# Getting the error "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" only on one site

Tags: oledb

I have seen many posts here and elsewhere regarding this error. In every case the solution is to either uninstall any 32-bit office components, or to change the target platform of the .NET project that's trying to access the driver to x86 instead of Any CPU. Neither of those solutions worked for me.

Here are the details. I have two ASP.NET sites on the same server running Windows Server 2008. One is a production site and the other is a staging site. I am trying to generate an Excel file via OLEDB. The production site produces the file with no problem. The staging site throws this error. Both sites are identical except for the host headers and the SQL Server database they connect to. The target framework for both is 4.5 and the App Pool is set to use 4.0.

Has anyone else come had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an IIS7 configuration problem. Each site had its own App Pool. On the advanced settings dialog, under (General), there is an attribute named Enable 32-Bit Applications. This attribute was set to True on the stage site. Changing it to False resolved the issue.